# How to add a options to a DropDownList with jquery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have a Table like this:

```
<table class="nav-justified" id="OrderTable">
```

Each row contain a DropDownList that should hold a options with numbers between 1 to 50 for example.
The DropDownList

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

I want to do it in jQuery.
thanks!

Comment: Can you please show us your code that you've attempted (the jQuery code).

Comment: does all the drop down have same values?

Comment: You want to do *what* 'in jQuery'?

Comment: Are you using Ajax call?

Comment: yes all the dropdown list need to hold the same value. i try to do it with jquery but i really dont know how.

Comment: Why are you doing that with Jquery? if in Asp.net you could do it by codebehind?

Comment: mm ok , and how can i do it in code behind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the ASP.net Dropdwon render like a `HTLM select` so:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

**Jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  for (var i=1; i < 51; i++)
    {
      $('#<%= DropDownList1.ClientId %>').append(new Option(i, i));
    }
});
```

where the new option is

```
$("#<%= DropDownList1.ClientId %>").append(new Option("option text", "value"));
```